# How many Stars do I need to complete the story?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

In Super Mario Galaxy 2, do I have to collect every star on every planet to complete the story portion of the game (I am not trying to collect everything, just what I need to progress)?

If not, what is the minimum amount of Stars that I need to complete the game - and by that I mean reaching the end of the story and (ostensibly) saving the princess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall, you need 70 stars in order to access Bowser's Galaxy Generator, the last boss stage. [Mario Wiki seems to agree](http://www.mariowiki.com/Bowser%27s_Galaxy_Generator).

This is the same number of stars you seems to need in all newer 3D Mario games.

Comment: and by 3D Mario games, I mean Super Mario 64, Super Mario Sunshine, and Super Mario Galaxy... although now that I look, Galaxy 1 only required 60 stars.